# How can I see my home folder in the finder?

Tags: finder

How can I go to my home folder in finder? and/or how can I navigate up a folder tree in finder

I am used to Ubuntu and finding /home/name easily in the gui

Answer (score 74, accepted):

- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> takes you to your home folder
- <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>UpArrow</kbd> takes you one folder up

Have a look at the "Go To" menu in Finder for additional key combinations. Some people like to use the <kbd>~</kbd> character and the **Go to Folder...** shortcut as that expands to the current user's home folder like on other UNIX operating systems.

You may also want to have a look at [Mac OS X keyboard shortcuts (HT1343)](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1343) which contains a huge list of OS X Lion keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 42):

In addition to the keyboard shortcuts, your home folder should be visible in the Finder sidebar by default:

[image: Finder sidebar]

If not, you can enable it in the Finder **Preferences**, under the *Sidebar* tab:
[image]

If the sidebar isn't visible, you can turn it on with **View → Show Sidebar** or **⌥⌘S**.

Comment: My home folder was not enabled by default, but I was able to follow the second step!

Answer (score 4):

You can set Finder's preferences (Command + ,) to open your home folder by default.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Open Terminal app.
Run this command:

```
open ~
```