# How to find a systems file on Mac

Tags: macos, mail.app

The answer to a previous question (that I share) suggested going to this file ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/Data/Library/Preferences.  How does one find that.  I don't know what ~/ references and the Library files that I find on my hard drive do not have a Container subfile

Comment: ~ is a shortcut to your user's Home folder. Use the Finder Go menu to go to your home (or the go to folder tip that @buscar mentions in his answer). See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/55408/how-can-i-see-my-home-folder-in-the-finder for more details on the use of ~ on OS X.

Answer (score 1):

If you hold down the <kbd>Option</kbd> key, your Library folder (`~/Library`), which is normally hidden, will show up under the Finders **Go** menu. Just selected it (Go -> Library) and you will be there in the Finder.

Answer (score 0):

Simply copy that information,

then in Finder window use the "Go" tab

then paste the `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/Data/Library/Preferences`

in to the pop up window and it will bring you to that place.

[image]

There are 2 Library locations on your drive.

One is the User Library, the other is the System Library

Comment: @Tetsujin I was wondering if I should explain that :) , thanks for doing it.